# How to check if number is NaN

Tags: postgresql, nan

I need to test if a numeric/float value in PostgreSQL is not a number (NaN). Note that ["PostgreSQL treats `NaN` values as equal"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html). As I'm not seeing any `isnan` function in PostgreSQL 9.3, here is my best attempt to make one:

```
create or replace function isnan(double precision) returns boolean as
  $$select $1::text = 'NaN'::text$$ language sql;
```

Is there any better way to test for `NaN`s?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is there any better way to test for NaNs?

Simply compare for equality:

```
SELECT double precision 'NaN' = double precision 'NaN';
```

as, per the docs you linked to, Pg treats `NaN`s as equal. I'm surprised by this, given that it correctly treats `NULL` as not equal to any other `NULL`, and would've expected `NaN` = `NaN` to return `NULL`, but ... well, it works.

Or if you want a function:

```
create or replace function isnan(double precision) 
language sql
immutable
returns boolean as $$
select $1 = double precision 'NaN'
$$;
```

Comment: Being relatively new to plpgsql, it seems to me that since `float` == `float8` == `double precision` (at least at the current time), you probably would want to pick one synonym and use it consistently.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `nullif`

```
select * from my_table where id = 209 and nullif(price, 'NaN') is not null;
```

Found this idea from this reply

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54542310/9473050

Answer (score 5):

Any NaN value taken with a minus sign still is a NaN value (just like a zero), so you can try this:

```
create or replace function isnan(double precision) returns boolean as $$
select $1 = -$1 and $1 != 0.0 $$ language sql;
```

or:

```
create or replace function isnan(double precision) returns boolean as $$
select $1 = -$1 and $1 = $1 + 1.0 $$ language sql;
```

As far as PostgreSQL treats NaN values greater than all non-NaN values, the following trick is possible:

```
create or replace function isnan(double precision) returns boolean as $$
select $1 > 0 and -$1 > 0 $$ language sql;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use typecasts to create an actual `NaN` value to compare against:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
    (1, 100),
    (2, 'NaN'::NUMERIC),
    (3, 300)
) A
WHERE column2 = 'NaN'::NUMERIC;
```

Which matches only the `NaN` values:

```
column1 | column2
--------+--------
      2 |    NaN
```

Comment: Why doesn't this work when one substitutes `INT` for `NUMERIC`?

Comment: @Vérace: I would guess because `NUMERIC` is an IEEE float which has a specific binary value allocated for use as `NaN`, whereas `INT` is a normal integer where all possible binary values are usable numbers - there is no value set aside for use only as `NaN`.  You would have to pick an `INT` value and decide for yourself to treat it as `NaN`, such as `0`, `-1`, `65536` and so on.  But it means you can't then use that number normally because you've now decided it means `NaN`.  The `NUMERIC` type handles all that logic for you.

Comment: Thanks for that - makes sense. I suppose one would have to delve into the source code to know for sure, but nice one! Makes sense! +1

Answer (score -2):

For Google BigQuery (and maybe other sql servers out there), use the following

```
SELECT * FROM [project:dataset.table]
WHERE IS_NAN(field) = true
```

Comment: The question is about postgresql, where IS_NAN is not defined