# what is an equivalent of NANVL(oracle function) in postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql, database-migration

I am trying to migrate an oracle DB application to postgres.
I can't seem to find an equivalent of NANVL in postgres. Is there a way to emulate the same ?

From the [Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions115.htm#SQLRF06311):

> The NANVL function is useful only for floating-point numbers of type BINARY_FLOAT or BINARY_DOUBLE. It instructs Oracle Database to return an alternative value n1 if the input value n2 is NaN (not a number). If n2 is not NaN, then Oracle returns n2.

Comment: It (posgresql) doesn't have such function. What you can do is a mix of `coalesce` with one of the functions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858859/how-to-check-if-number-is-nan

Comment: Since you're probably looking for answers from Postgres experts, you may want to explain what NANVL does in Oracle to spare them having to read Oracle documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Postgres you can compare a numeric value to the special constant `'NaN'`:

```
select some_column = 'NaN'
from some_table;
```

So you can write a function that will implement `nanvl()`:

```
create function nanvl(p_to_test numeric, p_default numeric)
  returns numeric
as
$$
   select case 
            when p_to_test = 'NaN' then p_default 
            else p_to_test 
          end;
$$
language sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Of course, a_horse_with_no_name is correct.

Everything is simpler: just a `CASE` with check on equality to NaN is needed  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/37528

Everything below is incorrect.

Similar to Jorge Campos advice: rip-off `isnumeric` from [isnumeric() with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195986/isnumeric-with-postgresql)
 and modify it to:

```
/* Ripoff https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195986/isnumeric-with-postgresql */
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nanvl(text, NUMERIC) RETURNS NUMERIC AS $$
DECLARE x NUMERIC;
BEGIN
    x = $1::NUMERIC;
    RETURN x;
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
    RETURN $2;
END;
$$
STRICT
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
GO
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/aee9d/1

Comment: According to [the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions115.htm#SQLRF06311) the function only checks for `NaN` not if a character value is a valid value. `nanvl('foo', 1)` will generate an error.