# Postgresql - how to treat NaN as 0 when summing?

Tags: postgresql, null, sum, aggregate-functions, nan

I have a table that contains numerical values and NaNs. When summing, if the selected values contain a NaN, the result will be NaN. Is there a way to make postgresql treat them as 0s when summing rather than NaN? Or do I just have to convert all NaNs in table to 0 or Null?

Comment: Try a CASE WHEN.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`NULLIF`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF), example:

```
with my_table(col) as (
values
    (1::numeric),(2),('NaN')
)

select sum(col) as original, sum(nullif(col, 'NaN')) as corrected
from my_table;

 original | corrected 
----------+-----------
      NaN |         3
(1 row)
```

Comment: How would you find the rows that are causing the sum to result in NaN? There are none that show as null.

Comment: @T.Young - Not sure what you mean. Simple check: `select * from my_table where col = 'NaN'`