# How to query the NaN values from an integer column in a Postgresql Database

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in my PostgreSQL DB in which I have a `numbers` column.
I want to query all the rows where the `numbers` column is a NaN.
When I try do so with `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE numbers='NaN'` I get the following error message : `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "NaN"`
I am using the Command line tool psql (PostgreSQL) 14.5 (Homebrew)
What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858859/how-to-check-if-number-is-nan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer columns in PostgresSQL cannot have NaN values. Those are limited to Numeric and Floating Point types. So the message is quite clear, that the syntax is invalid for `Integer` types.

Comment: Indeed, I was actually trying to keep the NULL values, that I mistook with NaN